# What is the "correct" way to make a stoppable thread in Python, given stoppable pseudo-atomic units of work?

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I'm writing a threaded program in Python. This program is interrupted very frequently, by user (CRTL+C) interaction, and by other programs sending various signals, all of which should stop thread operation in various ways. The thread does a bunch of units of work (I call them "atoms") in sequence.

Each atom can be stopped quickly and safely, so making the thread itself stop is fairly trivial, but my question is: **what is the "right", or canonical way to implement a stoppable thread, given stoppable, pseudo-atomic pieces of work to be done?**

Should I poll a `stop_at_next_check` flag before each atom (example below)? Should I decorate each atom with something that does the flag-checking (basically the same as the example, but hidden in a decorator)? Or should I use some other technique I haven't thought of?

Example (simple stopped-flag checking):

```
class stoppable(Thread):
    stop_at_next_check = False
    current_atom = None

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def do_atom(self, atom):
        if self.stop_at_next_check:
            return False
        self.current_atom = atom
        self.current_atom.do_work()
        return True     

    def run(self):
        #get "work to be done" objects atom1, atom2, etc. from somewhere

        if not do_atom(atom1):
            return

        if not do_atom(atom2):
            return

        #...etc

    def die(self):
        self.stop_at_next_check = True
        self.current_atom.stop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag checking seems right, but you missed an occasion to simplify it by using a list for atoms. If you put atoms in a list, you can use a single for loop without needing a `do_atom()` method, and the problem of where to do the check solves itself.

```
def run(self):
    atoms = # get atoms
    for atom in atoms:
        if self.stop_at_next_check:
             break
        self.current_atom = atom
        atom.do_work()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a "thread x should continue processing" flag, and when you're done with the thread, set the flag to false.

Killing a thread directly is considered bad form, because you might get a fractional chunk of work completed.

Answer (score 0):

A tad late but I have created a small library, ants, solving this problem. In your example an atomic unit is represented by an worker

Example

```
from ants import worker

@worker
def hello():
    print(“hello world”)

t = hello.start()
...
t.stop()
```

In above example hello() will run in a separate thread being called in a `while True:` loop thus spitting out “hello world” as fast as possible

You can also have triggering events , e.g. in above replace `hello.start()` with `hello.start(lambda: time.sleep(5))` and you will have it trigger every 5:th second

The library is very new and work is ongoing on GitHub https://github.com/fa1k3n/ants.git

Future work includes adding a `colony` for having several workers working on different parts of same data, also planning on a `queen` for worker communication and control, like synch